# ExtJS in Visual Studio (2010)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, extjs

Two questions:

1. How can I get JavaScript IntelliSense for ExtJS?
2. Are there any good tools (e.g. Extensions, NuGet packages) for working with ExtJS in Visual Studio?
3. Are there any good tools (e.g. Add-on Extensions like FireBug) for working with ExtJS in Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found these extensions useful when working with ExtJS in Visual Studio:

- [Javascript Parser](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/288a2b0f-1357-47b4-8215-1134c36bdf30) - makes it easy to find functions, shows todo comments
- [JSLint.VS2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/961e6734-cd3a-4afb-a121-4541742b912e) - code analysis, helps avoid coding mistakes

Answer (score 8):

To use intellisense in VS 2010 you need to reffer which files should be loaded for intelli sense. You can archive this with references in the docs where you want to use intelli sense:

```
/// <reference path="ScriptFile1.js" /> 
/// <reference path="Scripts/ScriptFile2.js" />
/// <reference path="../ScriptFile3.js" />
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/ScriptFile4.js" />
```

for more information on intellisense take a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx#Features)

For the tools part;

*Edit*

To Update on highlighting, braces, aso :

[Javascript tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed) is a great package directly by Microsoft

*editend*

[Javasript Parser](http://code.google.com/p/js-addin/) does a great work for me when writing

For testing & Debugging [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) is the best you get in my opinion, but you can also use the [IE developer tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359)(install only required for older IE, prior 8 if I am not mistaking) for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

try this http://www.dxdframework.com/, it's ext 3 integrated with msvs2010, examples are still for msvs2008, but as i know documentation will be updated soon. wiki: http://wiki.dxdframework.com/AllPages.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To answer point #2, I highly recommend [Ext.Net](http://ext.net) for working with ExtJS in Visual Studio, assuming you are using ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Best resources for wiring up IntelliSense for EXTJS in VS 2010+ is here:

http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/03/03/javascript-js-intellisense-auto_complete-in-visual-studio-11-beta-the-web-_references-js-file/

Note the "Updated" comment at the bottom:

> "...you can add files to the global JavaScript intellisense from the Visual Studio Tools –> Options Dialog."

This worked for me after I added "ext-all-debug-w-comments.js" to the list and turned off Resharper's IntelliSense for JS files only.